# Stacked column charts in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, stacked

Can some one please tell me how to make a Stacked Column Chart with the code? I've no dataset to bind, just plain values to display in a stacked column chart.
I'm using normal .NET Chart controls provided by Visual Studio 2010 in .NET Framework 40. So please refrain from talking about WebCharts or any other paid charting like Dundas charts or dotnetCharting etc..

Answer (score 2):

Setting the [SeriesChartType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype.aspx) to StackedColumn should give you the stack area chart if that is what you are asking. Code example below is from [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418)

```
            //Populate series data
            Random  random = new Random();
            for(int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
            {
                Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(45, 95),0));
                Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(5, 75),0));
                Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(5, 95),0));
                Chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(35, 95),0));
            }   

    Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    Chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    Chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    Chart1.Series["Series4"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zero7. Can you tell me how to edit the colors? And how to display the values on the Stack along with the total at the top?

Comment: You can edit a series color like: Chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;

Comment: Oh.. I actually got that one myself, the second question, I couldn't get.. about displaying the total on the top?

Comment: Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Label = "#VALY";

Comment: is there any way I can get rid of the graph in the background?? Thanks !

Comment: to remove the graph in the background, set Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False and Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False

Answer (score 1):

To remove the graph in the background set the following on the ChartArea object:

```
ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False
ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False
```

This will disable both Axis.

In the case where you want to keep the XAxis and its labels, remove the grid lines and the YAxis - you could use the following code:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.NotSet;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long search on stacked bar chart in .net with ASP Charts i got a better solution to that.

```
MobileSalesChart.Series["Apple"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Apple"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series["Nokia"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Nokia"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series["Samsung"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Samsung"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series["Sony"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Sony"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series["Motorola"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Motorola"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series[0].Points[i].AxisLabel = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Year"].ToString().Trim();
```